# Multiple errors when booting ubuntu (SGX disabled by BIOS among others)

Tags: boot, 22.04

Total noob here so please be patient:)
As the title says, when I boot my computer, I get multiple errors, I'm new at linux so I don't really know what they mean, here is a picture of the errors I get:[image: Errors]
I have a laptop Acer Nitro i5, I have never opened or modified it before.

When I first installed ubuntu I also had this errors but since I was changing from windows 10 I thought it was normal so I just let it pass, this error shows a few seconds and then my OS just boots without problem and I can use my computer without any inconvenience.

It was all okay until a week ago another problem showed up at booting, and this one didn't let my computer boot automatically, I had to execute the "fsck -f" command followed by my hard disk name (/dev/sda2) and fix the errors manually I had to do this every fourth time or so I used my computer. I heard that when this problem shows up regularly it means the hard drive is damaged, or the OS didn't install correctly, so I just reinstalled ubuntu an hour ago and I got the errors of the photo.

For now I have no problems, and I haven't used the fsck command, but I want to know, should I change my hard disk? are these problems something to worry about? Or can I use my computer and ignore them? Thank you all in advance for your attention and time:) I hope you all have a nice day!

Comment: If you're having to fsck over and over *and it keeps finding file system errors*, then it could be a failing hard drive. The fsck message here is not an error and is "clean". As far as the USB errors this could have something to do with devices connected to the USB bus. This can include devices that aren't actually plugged into USB ports like integrated cameras or fingerprint scanners. If you're not actually having any problems with your software or devices, I would not worry about these messages

Comment: In addition, the first line isn't an error. It's just telling you that feature is disabled.  The 2nd and 3rd lines are certificate errors but they might not be anything to worry about either. One example: some hardware may embed certificates in firmware and those certificates may have expired. Firmware updates may resolve those messages.

Comment: Thank you @Nmath !:)